# Pass query parameters from JS to Node JS GET request

Tags: javascript, node.js, database

Good morning,
I want to pass query argument to my database search from html site. I getting response from node js with this code:

```
app.get('/getdata', function(request, response) {

       console.log(request.obj)
       type=request.obj.type

       pool.connect(function (err, client, done) {
       if (err) {
           console.log("Can not connect to the DB" + err);
       }
       client.query("SELECT * FROM schema.table WHERE column1='"+type+"'", function (err, result) {
            done();
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.status(400).send(err);
            }
            response.send(result.rows);
       })
   })
});
```

And in js script in html:

```
var obj = {type:"Fiat", model:"500", color:"white"};
$.getJSON('/getdata', obj, function(response) {   console.log(response); });
```

While I query in database I want send some parameters from js to node.js request. Is there any way to pass variables in $.getJSON? And how to do it?

Thank you

Comment: You're doing it already. That's what `data` is!

Comment: @Quentin he means to get data by passing parameter.

Comment: @Timggwp — Again, that is what `data` (before it got edited out of the question) does.

Comment: I edited my example above, I have progress but I get error :  GET http://127.0.0.1:3000/getdata?type=Fiat&model=500&color=white 500 (Internal Server Error)

Answer (score 0):

As per the getJSON [docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) you can pass in an object as the second argument to getJSON and it will be passed in the query string of the request.

Answer (score 0):

Possible to pass,

```
$.getJSON('/getdata', obj, function(response) {   console.log(response); });
```

Cant remember exactly how to retrieve it from nodejs, think it was

```
app.get('/getdata', function(request, response) {
    request.obj
    ....
}
```

Comment: thanks, I have edited my example as you mentioned but I get a error GET 127.0.0.1:3000/getdata?type=Fiat&model=500&color=white 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: can you console log the response?

Comment: i figure this out, if you want get obj you should put: request.query.obj